No internet connectivity even though both wired and wireless connection is possible. All other devices in the network work fine
Specs
Ubuntu 20.04 LTE
The problem
Even though my connection is showing as up and I can connect to wireless and I have a wired connection my Ubuntu instance can't interact with the internet. It just shows as there is no connection but everything is showing like it's ok just can't connect.
Extra Context
Yesterday I wanted to upgrade Docker to the latest version so I followed these instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
Where it asks me to run a command to uninstall any other versions that might be there so I did that. After that I continued the tutorial and realized that my curl calls were not working, pings not working, etc. Unsure if this problem is related to this.
I have a pihole running in docker so unsure if it did some configuration to route all internet traffic to it but I don't see anything in the settings to say that it's using the pihole.
Like 4 hours after that happened suddenly things started working again and I don't know how to explain it.
That brings us to today. I tried to change the LAN IP address from 192.168.1.1 (default) to 192.178.1.1 which is what I usually have and it happened again, the internet dropped and nothing will fix it. For context on changing it to 192.178.1.1 when I was going to uninstall docker I preemptively changed the DNS settings on the router from the piHole to the ISP and it rolled me back to 192.168.1.1
Things I've done
In no particular order

Add a netplan file (/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml):

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4:true


run sudo nmcli networking on
run sudo dhclient enp0s31f6
Remove connection profile for the Wired connection (and add it back to the network manager conf file)
Run sudo service network-manager restart

Logs
I gathered these logs from running the wireless-info script recommended in this other thread
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rpGSRY7Tt5/
The Ask
I'm at a loss here I've reached the maximum of my level here on how to debug this problem could someone please help by pointing me at what else to do try to fix this issue so I can regain connectivity?

For anyone coming here later. I ended up factory reseting the machine to a fresh install of ubuntu and now things are working fine!
